# What is the technical term/name for the main repository in github?

Tags: git, github

A 'fork' is a copy of the main repository, but what is the main repository called ? Is there any technical term/jargon for it ?

Comment: "Upstream", usually - https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/merging-an-upstream-repository-into-your-fork

Comment: How about "the repository that this repository is forked from"?

Answer (score 1):

In generic terms, we call the main repository for a given project the *upstream repository*, or just *upstream*.  You can also just call it the main repository, and everyone will know what you mean.

On GitHub specifically, all the repositories that are associated with each other form a *repository network*, and the main one is said to be the *network root*.

Not all hosting platforms have the concept of a repository network, and of course repositories hosted on different platforms (like the main Git repo and the various contributors' repos) aren't part of a network, either.